# How to make a jsonp POST request that specifies contentType with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, jsonp

I need to make a jsonp POST request with the content type 'application/json'. I can get the POST request to the server like this:

```
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        error: error,
        async: true,
        complete: complete,
        timeout: TIMEOUT,
        scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: '_jsonp',
      });
```

But as soon as I add the line:`contentType: "application/json"` it starts sending it as an OPTIONS request rather than a POST.

How can I specify the content type and still submit the request as a POST?

Comment: Is the URL in your domain?  What format does it return?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is not possible to make a JSONP POST request.

JSONP works by creating a `<script>` tag that executes Javascript from a different domain; it is not possible to send a POST request using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: If I leave out the contentType, the request is made and the server gets it as a POST.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery falls back to XMLHttpRequest as you can't POST via `<script>` inclusion. But that means the JSONP response will never work; if it's coming from a different hostname you won't be able to read anything from the response due to the Same Origin Policy. `<script>` inclusion can only trigger a `GET`, any data you want to send to it must go in URL query parameters.

Comment: If you specify dataType: "jsonp" and type "POST", the "jsonp" takes precedent and it gets sent as a "GET" request (the "POST" gets ignored). Benefit is that this preserves the jsonp functionality, down-side is that it silently fails to POST and GETs instead (so you have to really be paying attention to catch it...)

Answer (score 7):

Use `json` in `dataType` and send like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "your url which return json",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(result){
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            error:function(xhr,status,error){
                alert(status);
            }
        });
```

and put this lines in your server side file:

if **PHP**:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
```

if **java:**

```
response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" ); 
response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST" ); 
response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000" );
```

Comment: Are there safety issue's involved with this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a (hack) solution I've did it many times, you'll be able to Post with JsonP.
(You'll be able to Post Form, bigger than 2000 char than you can use by GET)

**Client application Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // you request will be a post request
  data: postData, // javascript object with all my params
  url: COMAPIURL, // my backoffice comunication api url
  dataType: "jsonp", // datatype can be json or jsonp
  success: function(result){
    console.dir(result);
  }
});
```

**JAVA:**

```
response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" ); // open your api to any client 
response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST" ); // a allow post
response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000" ); // time from request to response before timeout
```

**PHP:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
```

Doing like this, you are opening your server to any post request, you should re-secure this by providing ident or something else.

With this method, you could also change the request type from jsonp to json, both work, just set the right response content type

**jsonp**

```
response.setContentType( "text/javascript; charset=utf-8" );
```

**json**

```
response.setContentType( "application/json; charset=utf-8" );
```

Please not that you're server will no more respect the SOP (same origin policy), but who cares ?

Comment: I think what you're talking about is really using CORS. By setting those headers you're triggering the client to initiate a CORS request. I wouldn't necessarily describe that as a "hack"; that's the way it should be done.  Moreover, I wouldn't recommend using "*" but instead echo back the client's origin and do a whitelist check on the server. See here for more details: http://enable-cors.org/server.html