# Error when returning value using JSONP

Tags: javascript, api, jquery, https, jsonp

I have a problem when using jsonp to API HTTPS website.
it will return below

```
response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=1592337329&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=&orderid=&type=sale&response_code=100&merchant_defined_field_6=&merchant_defined_field_7=&customer_vault_id=
```

and this is my code.

```
function getJSON() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:{},
        jsonp: true,
        jsonpCallback: "callbackName",
        url: 'https://secure.equitycommercegateway.com/api/transact.php?username=test123&password=test1234&ccnumber=4111111111111111&ccexp=1012&amount=10.00&type=sale&product_sku_1=monthly&callbackName=?',
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var callbackName = function(data) {
        //alert(data.listing.id );
    }
    getJSON();
});
```

It shows me a console error, Error to read response text..
and points to (=) symbol right before "SUCCESS" text.

anyone can help me?

Comment: Well, `response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS...` is not JSONP. It is a query string. Make sure you processing the return value appropriately.

Comment: The callback function should be global. Otherwise its not reachable from the injected script. Attach it to the window object or define it outside of the brackets.

Comment: ok then, how can I solved this? do you have any Idea?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make a JSONP POST request see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860117/1211981).