# My ajax call is always sending get request instead of post. why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

```
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: server_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: callback,
        data:req_json,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 60000,
        success: succeeded,
        error: got_error
    });
```

I am trying the above code for sending POST requset but at the server side is always receiving  GET request only , can anybody tell my why is this happening? thanks in advance..
server_url is like `http://ip:8007`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a jsonp POST request that specifies contentType with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860111/how-to-make-a-jsonp-post-request-that-specifies-contenttype-with-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate - [How to use type: “POST” in jsonp ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call). Answer explains why it can't be done.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot "post" when using dataType "jsonp". Because it creates a `<script>` element to get the data, so it has to be a get request.