# Kendo UI Scheduler datasource ignoring type:'POST" and using GET instead

Tags: kendo-ui

We are attempting to implement the Kendo UI scheduler and would prefer it to make a POST request to our backend for create and update events. The documentation indicates that you should be able to specify a type on the datasource transport to change type type of request being made. For example:

```
read: {
    url: "http://10.211.55.8/api/schedule/tasks",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "POST"
}
```

The default examples on Keno's site all exclude the type parameter but the documentation states this should work.

Here is a plunkr exmaple we are playing with: http://plnkr.co/edit/de6gGLuIelmbG2SglpBW?p=preview

If you monitor the tasks and create operation network requests you will see they are still being done via GET rather than a POST despite the type:'POST' option in the transport definition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the documentation says that it should **not** work. It says:

[image: JSONP and type disclaimer]

So for JSONP `dataType` only `GET` is supported.

You might also consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860117/1802671) very interesting and illustrative.

Comment: Thx. Figured it out just as you were posting that. Oddly, when testing last night I removed the datatype and it still wasn't working. Maybe not enough sleep. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case why did you answer your own question not adding any extra detail instead of accepting this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. DataType cannot be "jsonp" for a POST.